# Django getting related objects from M2M

Tags: python, django

For example, I have three Models in django:

```
class Car(models.Models):
    range = models.DecimalField()
    speed = models.DecimalField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.speed

class Group_of_Cars(models.Models):
    name = models.CharField()
    starting_city = models. CharField()
    car = models.ManyToManyField(Car)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Arrival_time(models.Models):
    Location_of_ArrivalPoint = models.CharField() 
    Last_known_location_of_CarGroup = models.CharField()
    Group_of_Cars = models.ForeignKey(Group_of_Cars)

    def function(self):

        "Get speed of the "Car" in "Group_of_Cars"

    def __str__(self):
        return self. Location_of_ArrivalPoint
```

This is an example of what I want to do, not my actual models. The idea is for the user to input a series of values for the type of "Cars" such as speed and range.  I'd like "Cars" to be selected when defining parameters for  "a Group_of_Cars". What I'm not sure how to do is how to get the speed of the car, for the Group_of_Cars for which I need to calculate an arrival time (Group_of_Cars consists of one type of car and I'd like 'Arrival_time' to be its own table).

Thank you for any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Car(models.Model):
    range = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=5)
    speed = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=5)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.speed)

class Group_of_Cars(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    starting_city = models. CharField(max_length=50)
    car = models.ManyToManyField(Car)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Arrival_time(models.Model):
    Location_of_ArrivalPoint = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Last_known_location_of_CarGroup = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Group_of_Cars = models.ForeignKey(Group_of_Cars, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def function(self):

        # "Get speed of the "Car" in "Group_of_Cars"
        return self.Group_of_Cars.car.all()

    def __str__(self):
        return self. Location_of_ArrivalPoint
```

In views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from core.models import Arrival_time
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    arp = Arrival_time.objects.get(Location_of_ArrivalPoint='Newyork')

    for i in arp.function():
        print(i)

    return HttpResponse()
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried this and I'm getting the error: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'objects' where 'speedvalue' is unable to be referenced.

Comment: I replicated your project created few objects and was able to access the car object from function.

Comment: since you are returning the speed from Car by __str__ , by calling function() you will get all the car objects(eventually there speed) belongin to the arrivalpoint's group.

Comment: This worked!! Thank you! And you're right, the field 'car' should be one to many.